# PHPMailer Works on WAMP but not on Production Server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Hello
I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send emails via SMTP. So, on my development server (WAMP on my computer), it works fine. The mail server I use is mail.jackbusch.net which is on the same shared host that I am going to upload the site to for production.

But when I DO upload the website, PHP mailer stops working and returns SMTP: Error: Could Not Authenticate (when I try to use localhost as the server) and SMTP Error: Could Not Connect (when I type in the full smtp server name--i.e. mail.jackbusch.net).

This seems odd to me since I have several Wordpress installations that send email notifications just fine--and WP uses Phpmailer, correct?

I don't even know where to begin on fixing this?

EDIT: Thanks for your suggestions--I ended up just using the PEAR Mail package and it works perfectly fine.

I used the second example shown here:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

I think one key difference is that before I was using Port 26, and the second time I was using the SSL port for my web host (a small orange). For whatever reason, it all worked out this time.

Comment: have you set authentication "on" in phpmailer? $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication

Comment: Some ISPs block port 25 (SMTP) traffic to "foreign" SMTP servers as an anti-spam measure. Try connecting to that mail server's port 25 directly via telnet or some other terminal emulator app. If they can't connect either, then it's not your code at fault and something else, like a firewall. You could try some of the alternate ports, like 587. But if your ISP's blocking port 25 traffic, they've probably blocked the standard alternates as well.

Comment: This could be a SSL/TLS issue rather than connectivity. Can you show the PHPMailer code you are using?

Comment: @pekka I think you were right--it was an SSL/TLS issue. Though it's still baffling to me why it would work on my localhost with the same exact phpmailer code and same mail server but not work when uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used PEAR Mail package instead with the SSL  example shown here:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm